# GitLab CI leaves docker images on the system

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running a GitLab runner in docker on my local system which creates a docker image of the repository and runs some tests. This is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

stages:
  - build
  - test

build image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

run-tests:
  stage: test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  script:
    - source /app/venv/bin/activate && pytest .
```

The problem is that this leaves docker images with a "none" tag that end up occupying a lot of storage as you can see from the image.
[image: list of images left created by the gitlab runner]

How can I avoid this? Is there an option to add in `gitlab-ci.yml` such that the container used is deleted after the last stage is completed?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [clearing the docker cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#clearing-docker-cache) as well as [clearing old build images](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#clearing-old-build-images) as per the official documentation.

```
/usr/share/gitlab-runner# ./clear-docker-cache
/usr/share/gitlab-runner# docker system prune
```

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation suggests using the command ```clear-docker-cache```. Running this command both on the system and in the docker container of the gitlab runner returns ```command not found```

Comment: I have updated the answer with a more accurate explanation of what I did. Hope this helps.